# how to inject angular1 service into angular2 =2.0.0 test spec with jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

****Getting an issue of No provider for LoginInfoService***
//Below is the source code of ng2 controller component. LoginInfoService has a dependency injection of service which is in ng1.

```
/// <reference path="../typings1/browser/definitions/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
'use strict';
import {TestBed, async, inject} from "@angular/core/testing";
//import {it, describe, expect, beforeEach, inject} from 'angular2/testing';
import {UnificationCtrl} from './unificationCtrl';
import {LoginInfoService} from './LoginInfoService';
describe('UnificationCtrl.', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
          TestBed.configureTestingModule(
            {
                //  declarations: [UnificationCtrl],  
                providers: [
                    UnificationCtrl,
                    OverviewUnificationService,
                    StarUnification,
                    SessionKeeper,
                    LoginInfoService,
                    OverviewCommonConstants
                ]
            });
    });

beforeEach(inject([OverviewUnificationService, StarUnification, OverviewCommonConstants], (OverviewUnificationService, StarUnification, OverviewCommonConstants) => {
    }));
    it('test isPendingStatus()', inject([UnificationCtrl, StarUnification], (UnificationCtrl, StarUnification) => {
        console.log('hi');
        expect(StarUnification.stat`enter code here`us.Pending).toEqual('PENDING');
        //    WirelessUsageModel.setBonus(true);
        //    expect(WirelessUsageModel.hasBonus()).toBeTruthy();
    }));

});
```

Comment: Can you show your test code and your component that uses the service

Comment: constructor(@Inject('AngularCacheService') private AngularCacheService:any,                
                public $log:LoggerService,
                public DashboardActivityBannerUtilityService:DashboardActivityBannerUtilityService,

Comment: how to inject angular1 service i.e AngularCacheSercvice in angular2 test spec

Comment: Please edit your post with a _complete_ example